# GCP terraform resource using data source secrets as value always wants to be updated in place by terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm using some data source secrets as values for a resource.

```
data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "myIp" {
  secret   = "myIp"
  version = 1
}
```

Then I use it in CloudSQL authorized networks:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "myCloudSql" {
  database_version = "POSTGRES_14"

      authorized_networks {
        name  = "my IP"
        value = module.myModule.myIp
      }

      # ...more authorized networks
```

so if I try to run terraform plan or apply even if no changes in infrastructure it will always try to `update in place` the authorized networks of the Cloud SQL resource.

Sample of output:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.myCloudSql.google_sql_database_instance.myCloudSql will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_sql_database_instance" "myCloudSql" {

        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ settings {
            # (11 unchanged attributes hidden)

          ~ ip_configuration {
                # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)

              - authorized_networks {
                  # At least one attribute in this block is (or was) sensitive,
                  # so its contents will not be displayed.
                }
```

Comment: What does the TF output say about that `myCloudSql` resource? Does it point at the secret value as being changed? Can you show a dump of that?

Comment: @lxop updqted with sample output of plan

Comment: Check in the state file, see if the actual network value is stored in there. It might be that it's not storing that secret value in the state, and so it doesn't know whether the value is up-to-date or not